# How to make Chef client use user specific nodejs version installed with NVM?

Tags: node.js, bash, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, nvm

I used nvm cookbook to install nvm and 4.3.1 version of Node.js.

```
include_recipe 'nvm'

nvm_install node['analyzer_agent']['nodejs']['version'] do
  user node['analyzer_agent']['user']['name']
  group node['analyzer_agent']['user']['group']
  from_source false
  alias_as_default true
  action :create
end
```

When I SSH to the server with the user (analyzer_agent in this case), everything works as expected. My default nodej.js version is 4.3.1 and when I manually try to install pm2 with `npm install pm2 -g` it works perfectly.

However, when I try to install pm2 module globally from my recipe:

```
execute "Install PM2" do
    cwd "/home/#{node['analyzer_agent']['user']['name']}"
    user node['analyzer_agent']['user']['name']
    group node['analyzer_agent']['group']
    environment "HOME"=> "/home/#{node['analyzer_agent']['user']['name']}", "USER"=>node['analyzer_agent']['user']['name']
    command "npm install pm2 -g"
    not_if { File.exists?("pm2") }
end
```

I'm getting the error below:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[Install PM2]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '243'
---- Begin output of npm install pm2 -g ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/analyzer_agent/.npm/pm2/1.0.2/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "pm2" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/analyzer_agent/npm-debug.log
---- End output of npm install pm2 -g ----
Ran npm install pm2 -g returned 243

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/runs/f3450c3b-d2cc-4f04-a504-436cee5c488b/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/analyzer_agent/recipes/nvm_nodejs.rb

13: execute "Install PM2" do
14:    cwd "/home/#{node['analyzer_agent']['user']['name']}"
15:    user node['analyzer_agent']['user']['name']
16:    group node['analyzer_agent']['group']
17:    environment "HOME"=> "/home/#{node['analyzer_agent']['user']['name']}", "USER"=>node['analyzer_agent']['user']['name']
18:    command "npm install pm2 -g"
19:    not_if { File.exists?("pm2") }
20: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/runs/f3450c3b-d2cc-4f04-a504-436cee5c488b/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/analyzer_agent/recipes/nvm_nodejs.rb:13:in `from_file'

execute("Install PM2") do
action [:run]
retries 0
retry_delay 2
default_guard_interpreter :execute
command "npm install pm2 -g"
backup 5
cwd "/home/analyzer_agent"
environment {"HOME"=>"/home/analyzer_agent", "USER"=>"analyzer_agent"}
returns 0
user "analyzer_agent"
declared_type :execute
cookbook_name "analyzer_agent"
recipe_name "nvm_nodejs"
not_if { #code block }
end
```

As much as I know setting HOME and USER with `environment` inside the `execute` should have do the trick. But I didn't have any chance. Chef client is only using compiled nodejs. Not the one installed by nvm.

What might be wrong?

(By the way, at the same server but with another user I compiled node.js from source and installed pm2 globally. I see a small possibility that it could be related to my issue, however, if it was the case, why it wouldn't do any harm while I'm installing pm2 in the new user account manually?)

Comment: The EACCES error means that you don't have permissions to create directory *pm2* in */usr/local/lib/node_modules*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install -g` is a global install, which means you need permission to write to the global folder where Node/NPM was installed (in this case `/usr/local/bin`). You probably mean to not use `-g`, as that only exists for humans, not tooling.

Comment: So how do I start my script? I need to do a `pm2 start my_app.json`.

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/pm2 start my_app.json`. For a packaged application this should generally be internal to the package via the `npm start` command.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in OpsWorks you can also override the version of Node installed by creating a new file in your app's cookbook: `attributes/customize.rb`. Then:

`normal[:opsworks_nodejs][:version] = '4.4.0'`

This should download the correct version of node instead of using Node 0.10... and thus the built-in OpsWorks application runner/monitor (monit) should work instead of having to install PM2.